# What is the best practice in PHP to create multiple objects if you know only their interface

Tags: php, oop, interface

I have a class to manipulate objects with defined interface

```
class TaskManager
{
    /**
     * @param TaskInterface $task
     * @param string $command
     * @return TaskInterface
     */
    public static function editTask($task, $command)
    {
        $task->setStatus(TaskInterface::TASK_STATUS_ACTIVE);
        $task->setCommand($command);   
        $task->taskSave();
        return $task;
    }
}
```

I can create single object by passing its instance as an method argument. This is pretty straightforward. But how should I create many of them?

```
public static function export()
{
    $commands = self::getCommandsToAdd();
    foreach($commands as $c){
        //This is wrong.
        $task = new TaskInterface();
        $task->setCommand($c);
        $task->save();
        //don't need to return it if it's saved
    }
}
```

I can't create it this way. And it's obviously a bad idea to pass array of  new objects. Another way is to pass a class name as a string and call its method to retrieve new object. But it seems wrong as well

Comment: Should (`public status function export()`) it be `static` or `status`?

Comment: yes, it's static, sorry

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured out a solution by myself. Can use a factory interface to pass a factory object.

```
interface TaskFactoryInterface
{
     public static function createNew();
}

/**
 * @param TaskFactoryInterface $task_factory
 */
public static function export($task_factory)
{
    $commands = self::getCommandsToAdd();
    foreach($commands as $c){
        $task = $task_factory::createNew();
        $task->setCommand($c);
        $task->save();
        //don't need to return it if it's saved
    }
}
```

What do you think?